# Android instrumentation test in Library module with Firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I have my project structured like the following:

```
project
  ∟ app // apply `google-services` and `firebase-crashlytics` plugins here
    ∟ google-services.json
  ∟ lib1 // including Firebase SDK, and Firebase related operations here
  ∟ lib2
```

It works well when running as a normal app. But when I run androidTest in `lib1`, I got the following exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this XXX. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

I tried to solve it by putting a `strings.xml` inside `/androidTest/values/res/` with the `google-services` related config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <! -- Present in all applications -->
    <string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">client_info/mobilesdk_app_id</string>

    <! -- Present in applications with the appropriate services configured -->
    <string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">${project_info/project_number}</string>
    <string name="default_web_client_id" translatable="false">${oauth_client/client_id}</string>
    <string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">${analytics_property/tracking_id}</string>
    <string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">${project_info/firebase_url}</string>
    <string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">${api_key/current_key}</string>
    <string name="google_crash_reporting_api_key" translatable="false">${api_key/current_key}</string>
    <string name="project_id" translatable="false">${project_info/project_id}</string>

</resources>
```

But then, I encountered another problem

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Crashlytics build ID is missing. This occurs when Crashlytics tooling is absent from your app's build configuration. Please review Crashlytics onboarding instructions and ensure you have a valid Crashlytics account.
```

I tried applying `firebase-crashlytics` plugin in `lib1` module, but I got the error

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Applying the Firebase Crashlytics plugin to a library project is unsupported. It should only be applied to the application module of your project to enable automatic upload of obfuscation mapping files for your application.
```

So I have to keep `firebase-crashlytics` plugin in `app` module.

Then I tried to move test into `app` module, but got another error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/internal/runner/tracker/UsageTrackerRegistry;
        at androidx.test.espresso.GraphHolder.baseLayer(GraphHolder.java:9)
        at androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.<clinit>(Espresso.java:2)
        at androidx.test.espresso.Espresso.onView(Espresso.java:38)
```

Any help is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Completely remove the firebase dependencies from the instrumented tests in that module by adding the following to your `build.gradle` file:

```
configurations {
    androidTestImplementation {
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase', module: 'firebase-perf'
    }
}
```

This way it won't complain anymore as firebase is not on the tests and that code should not be run if you have correctly replaced the repo or data sources before with your DI or using test doubles.